# Go to current translated node url?

Tags: uri, i18n-l10n

Im currently developing a module, that implements an ios-like-switch to change the language (max number of two languages!). The switch is a designed checkbox with the not-default language as the only option. So far I git it implemented.

The tricky part - and here i need some inspiration of the advanced folks here - is,

**How can i change the language of the site reasonably?**

I could just add the language prefix (en/de) for example to the url...but what happens if there is no translation?

**Questions:**

1. Is there a clever api that i can query like: "Does the current node have a translation?"
2. If true: give me the url of that node...?

I hope this questions are clear enough? If not please comment...

Any inspiration or ideas to implement that properly?

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/1280468

Comment: @AyeshK thanks for the link...the some ideas in it...